# Recommended way to develop using Jetty and Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, jetty

I am currently developing a J2EE application and I would like to use Jetty. I would like to have iot integrated with Eclipse, so I could debug the appliaction.

I've tried out couple of plugins (including WTP) but nothing works well enough. [Run Jetty Run](http://code.google.com/p/run-jetty-run/) plugin is the best, but I cannot specify context-root in it, which makes it unusable for me.

What would you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *but I cannot specify context-root in it, which makes it unusable for me*

You normally specify the context root in the project's properties, not in the server plugin. Rightclick the web project and navigate to *Web Project Settings*. There you can set the context root.

By the way, if you really want to get the most out of Eclipse to develop Java EE applications, you really should get "Eclipse for Java **EE** developers", and thus *not* "Eclipse for Java developers".

Comment: The EE edition of Eclipse is quite fine for developing Web Apps.  Just notice there is no server included, so you will need to configure one (and most likely download it too) which is a bit confusing if you end up doing it as part of something else.

Answer (score 0):

you could set a context in the run configuration.

I am not sure what you mean for context-root , 
you have a context for your application , and you want a root-context for static files?

If you have any question or feature request , 
please feel free to post in our issue tracker.

If that's a reasonable use-case , i will try to support in the next version.
http://code.google.com/p/run-jetty-run/issues/list

And also in the latest nightly version (will be official 1.3.2 version later) , 
we allow you to setup a jetty.xml , that could extend your jetty as you need.